# How do I switch a working copy with changes to the branch in svn-workbench?

Tags: svn

I created a lot of changes in my local clone of the svn repository.

```
/var/www/trunk_of_repo/
```

I don't want to commit these changes into the trunk.

how can I move all that changes into a new branch using svn-workbench on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope your branch has already been created. If you want to create a new branch you can do the following:

`svn copy Source_URL Branch_URL`

Now you can go to the working directory and issue the following command:

`svn switch Branch_URL`

Then you can commit the changes in the working directory to the branch.

`svn commit`

Comment: so you have to do it on the console? I thought maybe you can click somewhere in svn-workbench?

Comment: how does the source_url have to look like on linux?

Comment: so I guess it is `svn copy /var/www/trunk_of_repo/ http://svn.example.com/path/to/repository/branches/new_branch`

Comment: Source url will be the url from where you wanna create the branch. It can be from trunk or from some other branch. `svn copy   http://svn.example.com/path/to/repository/trunk   http://svn.example.com/path/to/repository/branches/new_branch`

Comment: I didn't commit my local changes yet, so I have to use /var/www/trunk_of_repo/ i guess